# Get title of Spreadsheet Google Spreadsheet api PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get the spreadsheet name. But It is not working. Can anyone help me please?
I am using php and Google spreadsheet and google drive api:

```
function getSheetTitle($spreadsheetID){
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Sheets');
    $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAuthConfig(GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS);
    
    $client = GoogleClientSheet();
    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
    
    $worksheetSheets = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetID);
    return $worksheetSheets->getTitle();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the getProperties()->getTitle()

```
function getSheetTitle($spreadsheetID){
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Sheets');
    $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAuthConfig(GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS);
    
    $client = GoogleClientSheet();
    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
    
    $worksheetSheets = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetID);
    return $worksheetSheets->getProperties()->getTitle();
}
```